# Understanding TRM calibration in network analyzers

Tags: calibration, vna

I am trying to figure out how TRM calibration in network analyzers works. I have read a couple papers about it, but didn't understand it properly, therefore I tried to develop it myself. I do this by drawing the signal flow graphs for Port 1 and Port 2 when the different calibration standards are connected and then trying to solve for the error terms given the measured S-parameters.

Consider the following signal flow graph for Port 1

[image]

where Gamma represents the `Match` or `Reflect`. For the Match, we have Gamma = 0 and therefore

- S11match = e4

If we use a short as the Reflect standard, we have Gamma = -1 and therefore

- S11short = e4 - (e1 * e3)/(1 + e2)

If Ports 1 and 2 are connected directly together, using the Thru standard, then we have the following signal graph:

[image]

And we can find the S-Parameters of this arrangement as follows:

- S11thru = e4 + (e1 * e3 * e8)/(1 - e2*e8)
- S21thru = (e1 * e5)/(1 - e2*e8)
- S12thru = (e7 * e3)/(1- e2*e8)
- S22thru = e6 + (e2 * e5 * e7)/(1 - e2*e8)

Similar to Port 1, we can draw a signal flow graph for Port 2 when the Reflect and Match standards are used, and the results are

- S22match = e6
- S22short = e6 - (e5 * e7)/(1 + e8)

Having developed these equations from the signal flow graphs, I can see that there are 8 unknowns (the error terms e1 through e8) and we have 8 measurements (S11match, S11short, S11thru, S21thru, S12thru, S22thru, S22match, S22short). Therefore, I thought it should be possible to solve this equation system such that the error terms can be determined from the S-parameter measurements. I tried to solve the equation system using Maxima, but it finds only a trivial solution with

- e1 = x
- e2 = -1
- e3 = 0
- e4 = s11match
- e5 = 0
- e6 = s22match
- e7 = y
- e8 = -1

for some arbitrary numbers x and y. So it seems to me that it is not possible to find the error terms from the measured S-parameters in this way, but I don't understand why this does not work. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, as it was over 4 decades ago that I did all this professionally, and I'm not going to go into the thoroughness to make it a definitive answer. However, it's far too long for a comment. It's a number of observations about your approach.

- You have too many unknowns. You can without loss of generality set e1 = 1 and e7 = 1, and now you can write e3 as your former e1.e3, and e5 as e5.e7. This may be what is stopping your solver from finding the non-trivial solutions.
- Once you have made this correction, it appears you could have enough measurements<sup>1</sup>. However, getting an algebraic solution is probably not what you need. The non-trivial result will be a forest of incomprehensible terms.
- In practice, we tend to do a full calibration of each one-port first. To calibrate the triple of unknowns e1.e3, e2 and e4, you need a triple of measurements. The most common methods are load, open, short, or three offset shorts (offshorts I used to call them). Any three knowns, reasonably well-separated on a Smith Chart, will suffice for calibration.
- While it's tempting to say that a short has reflection coefficient 1, and use that simplification to try to write down explicit equations, I find it better to allow all the calibration pieces to be a complex number, and to write the results of the measurement process down in matrix form. This makes the measurement, and solution, process symmetrical in the three measurements. It also allows one to use different lengths of short, open with radiation etc, without changing the approach. Finding the inverse of a 3x3 matrix is straightforward (I used Cramer's Rule, which will work algebraically as well as numerically). You either grok matrix notation, or you don't. If not, and you want some intuition to push through the matrix maths, then run a few examples with simple values for the errors, and see what happens.
- Once you have the two one-ports calibrated, then you can do your through-connected measurements. As before, the thru may not be gain 1, but have some electrical length. You now find that you have an excess of measurements over unknowns, as now e2 can be measured by port 2 through the thru, as well as falling out of the one port calibration of port 1. They should of course be the same, in practice they will be slightly different. In a real VNA box, there is often a single RF source that is switched between ports. These switches may not be perfect, so e2 **could actually change** between port 1 or port 2 transmitting. Even in a two-source VNA, the difference will give you a good check on the size of your measurement noise and errors.
- I found the following notation helpful. My 'perfect' VNA has ports 0 and 3, making measurements m03 etc. My real VNA has ports 1 and 2. The device parameters are S12 etc. The error S-parameters boxes are then denoted e10 etc on port 1, e23 etc on port 2. It just means you can write everything down on a flow graph, with all your gain terms having obvious meanings (which is more apparent, your e8, or my e22?)

(1) I am not going to try to wrap my head around this too hard, but I **suspect** that as you are not making a triple of (well separated) measurements on each port, your resulting measurements are not independent. That is, you have 8 measurements, but at least one of the measurements could be derived from a linear combination of the others, so you don't have enough (in matrix parlance, they are rank-deficient)
. Understanding this issue never really arose during my work, as we never even attempted to do what you are trying to do. The practice was to work from full one-port cals, up to a two-port.

Comment: thanks for your comment. From a first look, it may seem that I don't have enough measurements, but I know that calibration with THRU-REFLECT-MATCH works, because my R&S ZVA at work allows for this option. The reason I prefer TRM over SOLT is that I can avoid the OPEN standard, which is somewhat difficult to make.

Comment: If the ZVA does it, then it must be mathematically possible. You are missing a simpolification, and a complication. You can subtract e4 directly from S11thru, and the e2.e8 term needs to be multiplied by the product of the thru actual electrical length - this is why you need to adopt my notation, to separate what you call S21thru, which would be my measurement m30thru, and the value of the electrical length of the thru line which ought to be called S21thru! I wonder if the length of the thru line (which you don't allow for) pushes you round the Smith Chart enough to resolve the equations.